# Outlook 365 From Address Drop Down Empty

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-addins

We have our server code which talk to Outlook using our Plugin developed using MAPI C++.

I recently updated my Outlook 365 to latest updates and since then it stopped displaying From address/display name on New/Compose Mail windows. If I revert back to any other Outlook version it's working fine.

The property I can assume can be : PROP_ACCT_NAME or PROP_ACCT_USER_DISPLAY_NAME, both gets set properly in my code but still it's not showing display name for From field on New Mail window.

Any pointer, which property is responsible for From field, display name on New/Compose Mail window?

Is there any new property or some change in Outlook 365 with latest updates?

Please find screen shot for reference.

[image]

Regards,
Mahesh

I tried with removing display name from the email account and it shows From field.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W` `(http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F`) property using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` - do not use Extended MAPI for that (`IMessage::SetProps` or `HrSetOneProp`).

Answer (score 0):

The [PROP_ACCT_USER_DISPLAY_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/prop_acct_user_display_name) property returns or sets the user display name of the user. The [PROP_ACCT_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/prop_acct_name) property returns or sets the account name. They cannot be used for setting the sender on the emails.

There is no need to use any low-level API for that. If you develop an Outlook COM add-in you can use the following properties that the Outlook object model provides:

- [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. The other account must configured in Outlook for that.
- [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) which returns or sets a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. In that case you have sufficient privileges to send on a behalf of another person in Exchange.

MAPI is just a low-level API which doesn't provide anything for building COM add-ins. When you build a COM add-in you have got access to the Outlook object model where you can use any low-level API. Any usage of the low-level API must be reasonable. And if you need to deal with any UI related changes I'd suggest using the Outlook object model instead.